# Creating keystroke issue in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, webview, keystroke

I am creating my first android app using android studio electric ell,
But every time i tried to create keystroke and after inserting all required data, the message "Failed to create keystroke" appears.
I tried many times and tried many solutions... But aame result
Any ideas could help

1.change the location
2.change details

Same result
When i test the app it works the way it should be

Clarification :
[every time i try to finish this page .. the same error appears ..
"Failed to create keystroke"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FKu9Z.png)

Comment: Can you please share the SS of input details?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I updated the question .. and added a screenshot to the window I facing the problem in ..